# how to pass inputs into url in android

Tags: android, ios

i have developed an ios app that is now to be implemented as an android app as well.
i am new to android and am having problems with the url format.

i am feeding uname and pwd info in ios via the following code:

```
NSString *checkForLogin  = [NSString stringWithFormat:[[@"http://" stringByAppendingString:IP] stringByAppendingString: @"&what=LoginCheck.php&un=%@&pwd=%@" ],username.text,pwd.text];
```

for android, i am not getting the correct final url by using the following code:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("un", un.getText().toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pwd", pwd.getText().toString()));
       HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(constants.URL + "&what=LoginCheckJava.php" );

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF_8"));
```

The final url shoud be:xxxxxxxx/loadhtml.php?where=DeliverySystem&what=LoginCheck.php&un=usertest&pwd=1234567890

pls help. thx

Answer (score 0):

You can call  this task  with

```
new PostMethodTask().execute("xxxxxxxx/loadhtml.php");
```

and this task it will work fine for you

```
private class PostMethodTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

        String responseString = null;

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("where", "DeliverySystem"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("what", "LoginCheck.php"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("un", "usertest"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pwd", "1234567890")); 

        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
                return responseString;
            } else {
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: any idea why my current code is wrong? i cant seem to generate the url to view it in the console also.